# Conversion from Option to Try

Tags: scala, error-handling

Recently I found myself writing a generic utility to convert `Option` to `scala.util.Try` like this:

```
implicit class OptionTry[A](oa: Option[A]) extends AnyVal {

  def asTry[E <: Exception](e: E): Try[A] = oa match {
    case Some(a) => Success(a)
    case None    => Failure(e)
  }

  def asTry(msg: String): Try[A] = asTry(new Exception(msg))
}
```

Now I am wondering why the standard library does not provide it. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question may be off-topic because I don't there's much answer other than opinion or speculation, but here's my speculation.

`Try` was introduced to provide an alternative to the `try`-`catch` syntax. Exceptions are somewhat frowned upon in the Scala world, and `Try` is there to help you deal with APIs that throw, not to encourage you to use exceptions.

It seems like you're using this in situations where `Either` may be more appropriate than `Try`. For example, instead of writing `o.asTry("xyz")` to get a `Try[A]`, I'd suggest `o.toRight("xyz")` to get an `Either[String, A]`.

Comment: Thank you. I did not want to use `Either` since it's unbiased. I did not want to use `\/` of  `scalaz` either. So I am trying to use `Try` as a right-biased `Either` but now I see they  are not exactly the same.

Comment: http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.$bslash$div the `Either` in Scalaz sounds like the thing you are looking for especially `\/-`

Comment: @AndreasNeumann Thanks but I did not want to use `scalaz` (or any other 3d party dependency). So I am trying to use `Try` _instead of_ `\/`.

Comment: Although if the essence of your question is why you keep finding yourself having to roll your own generic utilities, I think refusal to use libraries is the answer.

Comment: On further thought - If you want a right-biased `Either`, isn't that exactly what `Either.RightProjection` is?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Does `Either.RightProjection` provide an access to the _error_ (left) part as `Try` does ?

Comment: Only via `.e`, I suppose. It's definitely not as nice as `\/` :(

Answer (score 4):

As Chris Martin already suggested the difference lies in the semantics.

Being `None` is nothing exceptional for an `Option`-Type, it is an expected behavior.

So having a conversion from `Option` to `Try` can be seen as a special behavior where there is no standard way to express this that is suitable for all users. A hint for this could be that you need to give the expected Exception in the converter function.

An appropriate solution could be to change the implementation that returns the `Option` to use `Try` instead, instead of adding the behavior afterwards. (If this is possible  and not the whole cause of the implicit class ;) )